# Eloquent "Query Builder" with "OR" operator neutralizes my Global Scope - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, scope

## ⛳ What I need:

I am developing an application in `Laravel 5.4` and I want a `global scope` that allows me to filter different elements of the application depending on the user that created them.

---

## My global scope:

I have a class `BaseEloquentModel.php` who extends `Eloquent` and all my models extends from this class. I have a `global scope` as follow:

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    static::addGlobalScope('', function(\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $builder) use($userId) {
        /**
        * I get the name of the table with <code>(with(new static))->getTable()</code> 
        * and then filter the query for the <b>user_id</b> field
        */
        $builder->where(
            (with(new static))->getTable() . '.user_id', 
            '=',
            $userId
        );
    });
}
```

---

## ⛔ The problem

When I have a query like this, with `or` operator, the global scope is "neutralized":

```
$qBuilderCars = Car::whereRaw("name like ? or id = ?", [
    '%' . $searchCriteria. '%',
    $searchCriteria
]);
```

If I call the `toSql()` method on  `$qBuilderCars` I see that it *"correctly"* adds the `AND` operator to the end of the query.

```
select * from `cars` where name like ? or id = ? and user_id = ?
```

Maybe you've already noticed my problem ... If the element's builder, in this case `cars`, has used an `OR` operator, then the global scope will not help, since there is no parenthesis between `where name like ? or id = ?`. So the resulting query would be something similar to the following:

```
select * from `cars` where name like ? (or id = ? and user_id = ?)
```

So this query will return all cars whose name matches or whose ID is the one received and has been created by the user...

When what I need is:

```
select * from `cars` where (name like ? or id = ?) and user_id = ?
```

## My attempts

I tried to alter my `global scope` to try to make the `AND` operator that I add the most restrictive in the query, but without any success.

**I can not manually add parentheses to all the application's queries, so ... Is there a way to add global parentheses from the global scope to the `builder`?**

---

## The solution

The solution is to add parentheses to all the raw queries.

- ✅✅ You can see the [@Styx solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55765899/4359029) which I consider the most successful
- I will also [leave my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55758674/4359029), which acts directly inside the `global scope`, and which I consider interesting to be able to see how an `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` object works

Comment: Which is laravel version? Because in laravel 5.2 parentheses added as you need by default when global scope is applied.

Comment: Is `Laravel 5.4` and the parentheses are not being added automatically :-S

Comment: @yrv16 Could you show me the documentation about that?

Comment: I have installed 5.4 and really there no parentheses in query as in 5.2 version. I have found information that global scope implementation has been re-written. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade

Comment: @yrv15 First of all, thank you for your time. Wow, what a pity that `Laravel 5.4` global scope has changed. I think the only thing that I can do is to try to see how they introduced those parentheses to replicate it in my application...

Comment: You are welcome if I find decision I reply.

Comment: @yrv16 Thank you. Let's see if between the two we find a solution. Anyway, you can move your comment to an answer so I can rate it :-)

Comment: What exact version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @Styx Laravel 5.4

Comment: You mean `5.4.0`?

Comment: @Styx First of all, thank for your time. I think that from Laravel 5.4 there are only two versions 5.4 and 5.4.22, the latter corrects a vulnerability. The one I'm using is 5.4.22.

Comment: Show, please, how exactly you define your global scope, and what exact code products wrong SQL. I just can't reproduce that error.

Comment: @Styx I updated my answer. If you need other details, please, ask me.

Comment: You've shown how you "neutralize", but what code produces _wrong_ SQL?

Comment: We couldn't reproduce this because of `whereRaw()`. With `where('name', 'like', '%'.$searchCriteria.'%')->orWhere('id', $searchCriteria)`, Laravel adds the parentheses automatically. I assume you have to use `whereRaw()`?

Comment: @Styx @Jonas Staudenmeir I use `whereRaw`, please see my `$qBuilderCars` in my question

Comment: @Styx , Jonas Staudenmeir Could you give me your opinion about the answer I have published to my own question? Apparently it works; but I do not know if it can have repercussions that I am not taking into account.

Comment: @tomloprod Why don't you just use normal `where` and `orWhere` instead of `whereRaw`?

Comment: @Styx I apply this `global scope` in a very large application with too many `whereRaw` so I can't modify them and check the stability of the application. In addition there are no automated tests ☹...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it seems that your solution to add parentheses is the best workaround, but I have a suggestion how to do that slightly better way.

1. Create new class `QueryBuilder`. For example, in `\App\Models\` namespace (`app/Models/` folder):

   ```php
   namespace App\Models;

   use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder as EloquentQueryBuilder;

   class QueryBuilder extends EloquentQueryBuilder {

     public function whereRaw($sql, $bindings = [], $boolean = 'and')
     {
       return parent::whereRaw('('.$sql.')', $bindings, $boolean);
     }

   }
   ```
2. Add this code to your `BaseEloquentModel` class:

   ```php
   use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
   use App\Models\QueryBuilder; // <-- addition

   class BaseEloquentModel extends Model {
     // ...
     protected function newBaseQueryBuilder()
     {
       $connection = $this->getConnection();

       return new QueryBuilder(
           $connection,
           $connection->getQueryGrammar(),
           $connection->getPostProcessor()
       );
     }
     // ...
   }
   ```

Now, all `whereRaw()` calls will automatically have parentheses around query.

Comment: +1 It seems an interesting way to do it! The only thing I find missing is, in this way, you would not cover other `eloquent` methods like `orWhereRaw()`. I understand that with my solution, being within the global scope of my `BaseEloquentModel`, it would apply to all raw queries, no matter how they were generated, right?

Comment: @tomloprod `orWhereRaw` is calling `whereRaw` internally, so that will be covered as well :)

Comment: @tomloprod Sorry, messed up with explanation. Both our methods will be applied to all models extended from `BaseEloquentModel`, but mine is without foreach/modify overhead.

Comment: You have finished convincing me. And using that solution, I do not feel so guilty about going through the queries in a loop  I will try your solution in a few minutes. Thanks!

Comment: @tomloprod Btw, if your code is using `havingRaw`, you can override this method as well.

Comment: Works like a charm!  Do you know if  `->select(DB::raw("..."))` call `whereRaw` internally? What worries me is the possibility that the application is using some other method such as `whereRaw` or `havingRaw` and that, due to ignorance, I did not override it in my "*CustomQueryBuilder*"

Comment: @tomloprod `select()` most definitely does _not_ call any `whereRaw()` internally :) And you should not worry about `select()` or `DB:raw()`, this code won't affect them (and shouldn't).

Comment: I got confused when writing this comment. Too much movement between foreign code today   I do not bother you anymore, one last question. Do you know any other method, like `whereRaw` or `havingRaw` that can "alter" queries in a raw way?

Comment: @tomloprod Yes, there is `orderByRaw`, but it shouldn't cause you such issue with parenthesis. Your issue with `where` only, right?

Comment: Yes, I think so. At least for now... Thank you for all your time. I prefer your answer to mine, so I will mark it as accepted. :-)

Answer (score 0):

## The solution...?

I found a "solution", before apply my global scope I loop through all `where` clauses whose type is `raw`:

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    static::addGlobalScope('', function(\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $builder) use($userId) {

       /**
        * My workaround to prevent a raw query from neutralizing the global scope.
        * We go through all the queries and, if they are raw, encapsulate them in parentheses.
        */
        $wheres = $builder->getQuery()->wheres;
        foreach ($wheres as $iWhere => $where) {
            // If where clause is "raw" I wrap with parenthesis.
            if ($where['type'] == 'raw') {
                $builder->getQuery()->wheres[$iWhere]["sql"] = "({$where['sql']})";
            }                                                      
        }

       /**
        * I get the name of the table with <code>(with(new static))->getTable()</code> 
        * and then filter the query for the <b>user_id</b> field
        */
        $builder->where(
            (with(new static))->getTable() . '.user_id', 
            '=',
            $userId
        );
    });
}
```

I do not know if this solution will have any unexpected repercussion or if it will affect in excess the performance of the queries...

Will return the next SQL:

```
select * from `cars` where (name like ? or id = ?) and `cars`.`user_id` = ?"
```

Comment: I don't see any obvious issues. Of course, it's not very elegant, but probably the best workaround for your situation. You could simplify it with a reference: `foreach($wheres as &$where) { [...] $where["sql"] = [...]`

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Yes, it's not very elegant I would like to find some other solution that solves this problem. 

With regard to passing it as a reference, it was my first attempt; but for some reason it does not work. (*I just tried it again with your comment code*)

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I agree with you. Although the advantage that I see with this system (*or any other that adds the parentheses automatically*) is that, even if some programmer makes an error and does not use them in their `whereRaw`, the `global scope` will continue to work. Do not you think? 

Maybe there is some way to achieve this same result; but eloquently...

Comment: IMO, you should never have something like `whereRaw("name like ? or id = ?")` without parentheses in your application. You basically can't add any more constraints to this query without breaking it.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I agree with you. Unfortunately not everyone is aware of this and perhaps a code like this could serve as a "barrier" for a bad practice to affect something as important as an `global scope`, right?

BTW, for your contributions to Laravel I see that you understand in depth how `eloquent` works. Do you consider this `workaround` something valid to use in a production environment? Can you think of any other more elegant / efficient way? 

P.S.: Thank you for your time.